# Save & Resume link

Tags: cognito-forms

Are there any plans to be able to go to your Save & Resume link that gets emailed to you after the form has already been submitted?

For example our forms can get very long and I'd like my service technicians to be able to save the form before they submit it and then send it.  If the person who receives the form notices there's an error they would like to let the technician know and then the tech could recall the submitted form, correct the errors and resubmit.  Other than that Save & Resume works well.  Good job.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we are planning to add support in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) for allowing these links to work post-submission.  We just held off on the first release to bring this to market faster and get feedback.  We plan to allow you to enable post-submission editing and conditionally control view/edit permissions based on the data on the form, so you can for example allow editing until the request is marked as "Accepted", etc.

Please let us know if you have specific suggestions for how this should work, as we are trying to support a wide range of entry workflow scenarios.  Also, check out the new support for multiple confirmation emails, including the ability to conditionally send emails when entries are updated by administrators.  This will likely factor into your workflow needs.